# lxc-start: controller: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 842 Received container state "STOPPING" instead of "RUNNING"

Tags: networking, containers, ubuntu-18.04, lxc, telecommunication

when i run the config file

config file

sudo lxc-start -n controller -d

it gives me this error

lxc-start: controller: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 842 Received container state "STOPPING" instead of "RUNNING"

lxc-start: controller: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 330 The container failed to start

lxc-start: controller: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 333 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode

lxc-start: controller: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 336 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options

Additional information

lxc-start --version

3.0.3

uname -a

Linux shahrukh-VirtualBox 3.12.74-031274-generic #201705101001 SMP Wed May 10 14:04:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there were old config files for `apparmor` in my system that didn't get updated along with `apparmor`. Simply doing this fixed it:

```
sudo -sH              # become root
apt purge apparmor*   # uninstall apparmor and its configs
apt install apparmor* # reinstall it
apparmor_status       # check if apparmor is running

# If the above status shows 0 for every profile or other error
# check first if apparmor is activated in the kernel through grub
cat /sys/module/apparmor/parameters/enabled

# if the above doesn't return "Y", then activate it first
mkdir -p /etc/default/grub.d
echo 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT apparmor=1 security=apparmor"' \
  | tee /etc/default/grub.d/apparmor.cfg
update-grub
reboot
```